# doctrine:schema:update doesn't retrieve production configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've declared a configuration in **app/config/config_prod.yml** so I can execute commands on the remote database.

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     the-ip
        dbname:   the-database
        user:     the-user
        password: the-password
```

But when I run  `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql -e=prod` it still uses the configuration set in **parameters.yml**.

A `var_dump($this->getApplication()` in the `execute` method in **Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand** shows the right environment doesn't get the configuration from **config_prod.yml**

```
public $parameters =>
  array(428) {
    ...
    'kernel.environment' =>
    string(4) "prod"
   ...
    'database_host' =>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
```

Did I encounter a bug or is this command not capable of dealing with different environments?

Comment: Dôh! Didn't think that would be stored in the cache. Cleared the cache for the production environment and the right configuration is being used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: You have to clear the cache after every configuration change in the prod environment. In the dev environment the cache is rebuild (some parts not) on every request. But not in prod.

Indeed, configuration is compiled into cache. Loading the configuration from YAML/XML on every request would be too heavy. Look for the method `getDefaultParameters()` in `app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php` and you can see, all configuration parameters are merged in a huge big array.

You will notice, the parameters in this array, are not often the same, you configure in your `config.yml`. The injecting of these parameters depends on the bundle and their specific extension class. See [Semantic Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) for further infos.